# Can't make users login for long time like' Facebook'

Tags: php, cookies

I made a website that allows you to login for a long time like Facebook to make this system I used cookies and I make the expiration after 1 year and I made a function to check cookies but some users are kicked out and I don't know why this is the code to check the token and cookies
I use token and I save it in my database

```php
public static function checkToken($conn) {
    //header('Location: login.php');
    
    if (isset($_COOKIE['token']) && isset($_COOKIE['username'])) {
        //$_SESSION['username'] =$_COOKIE['username'];
        //$_SESSION['token'] = $_COOKIE['token'];
    
        $username = $_COOKIE['username'];
        $query = $conn->prepare("select * from session where username =?");
        $query->execute([$username]);
        if ($query->rowCount() > 0) {
            $rows = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            foreach ($rows as $row) {
                $token1 = $row['session'];
                $gent = $row['agent'];
            }
            if ($_COOKIE['token'] != $token1) {
                // session_destroy();
                header("Location: /login");
                // set the expiration date to one hour ago
                setcookie('token', null);
                setcookie('username', null);
                exit;
            }
        } elseif ($query->rowCount() == 0) {
            // session_destroy();
            header("Location: /login");
            // set the expiration date to one hour ago
            setcookie('token', null);
            setcookie('username', null);
            exit;
        }
    } else {
        // session_destroy();
        header("Location: /login");
        // set the expiration date to one hour ago
        setcookie('token', null);
        setcookie('username', null);
        exit;
    }
}
```

and this for the login

```php
public static function login($conn) {
    $user = filter_var($_POST['username'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $pass = filter_var($_POST['password'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    
    $query = $conn->prepare("select * from users where username= ? and password = ?");
    $query->execute([$user, $pass]);
    if ($query->rowCount() > 0) {
        $rows = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            $username = $row['username'];
        }
        $token = funcs::getToken(10);
        $_SESSION['token'] = $token;
        setcookie('token', $token, time() + (365 * 24 * 60 * 60));
        setcookie('username', $username, time() + (365 * 24 * 60 * 60));
        //setcookie('year', $_SESSION['year'], time() + ( 365 * 24 * 60 * 60) );
        //setcookie('pre', $_SESSION['pre'], time() + ( 365 * 24 * 60 * 60) );
        $gettoken = $conn->prepare("select * from session where username= ? ");
        $gettoken->execute([$_COOKIE['username']]);
        if ($gettoken->rowCount() == 0) {
            $query1 = $conn->prepare("insert into session (username,session,agent)values(?,?,?)");
            $query1->execute([$user, $_COOKIE['token'], $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']]);
        } else {
            header('Location: /index');
            exit;
        }
        header('Location: /index');
        exit;
        ob_end_flush();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Remember, cookies are stored on the clients browser, if they use a different browser (no cookie) If they clear cookies (no cookie) if they set their browser to clear cookies periodically (no cookie)

Comment: yes I know but sometimes they are kicked without doing any thing it just happens to me before 10mints because I was downloading a file from the website suddenly the cookies was deleted

Comment: Your architecture is not secure. Once the user logs in, you create a cookie with the "username" which is plaintext and not secured (in a method of signing the value, or encrypting it). The 'session' here doesn't really do anything in terms of authenticating the user, it seems you're tracking the device which again can be overwritten. Looking over your code fast, what stops me creating a valid account then modifying my 'username' in my cookies then reloading the page. In theory, this is all that is needed to break out the authentication and browse as any 'user'.

Comment: I don't understand you can you explain for me what can I do?

Comment: I use token and username so if any one change the username the script will check in the database and will kick him from the website

Comment: Not if it's changed to the username of another real user

Comment: just a question can the cookies be deleted automatically with out doing something to them??

Comment: because U think that the cookies deleted by it self I don't know why

Comment: Any user can clear the cookies from their browser with the click of a button. So, they can be deleted without involvement from your PHP code. Similarly they can be modified by the user too.